# RC circuit with a switch

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

The problem wants the value of R1, R2, and C.

I have no idea to solve it.
How can I use the output voltage to find the values of the resistances and the capacitance?

Comment: hi! sadly, we don't know how to help you, because we don't know where you are stuck. Please tell us what you have tried, and ask 1 precise question which can help you solve this on your own.

Comment: Suggestion: Start by writing some KVL and KCL equations and determining initial conditions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be homework, but does not show any work by OP

Comment: I understand how hard this question feels for you and I see that this is a great challenge. However, you should first make an attempt yourself step by step; you might find clues that might help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Think it like this. Assume that the circuit attained steady state before the switch got closed. The capacitor is fully charged up with no variation.
In this state,
$$24*\frac{4}{4+R_{1}+R_{2}}=\frac{96}{4+R_{1}+R_{2}}=12 V$$
The voltage across the capacitor cannot change suddenly.
$$96=48+4R_{1}+4R_{2}$$
$$48=48+4R_{1}+4R_{2}$$
$$12=R_{1}+R_{2}$$
For the final steady state after the switch is closed,
$$R_{1}$$
is shorted. The capacitor finished discharging by then.
The final value of the requested voltage is 8 V.
So, the voltage across
$$R_{2}$$
is 16 V in the final steady state after closing the circuit.
The current flowing is 2A in the 4 ohms and R2 resistors.
The value of R2 is 8 ohms.
The value of R1 is 12-8=4 ohms.
Now, as the switch is closed, the capacitor is parallel with 2 resistors, so the resistance seen by the capacitor is
$$8||4=\frac{8}{3} \Omega$$
The time constant =
$$\frac{1}{RC}$$
The equation for capacitor discharge has a exponential of the form
$$e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}$$
$$2=\frac{1}{C*\frac{8}{3}}$$
$$\frac{16}{3}=\frac{1}{C}$$
$$C=\frac{3}{16} F $$